# Visual Studio Debugger C++ - breakpoints not recognized

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Beginner programmer using Visual Studio release January 2021 on Windows 10. I have yet to get breakpoints to work. When placing a breakpoint in the helloworld.cpp program below and running the debugger, I get the following message and no breakpoint is set.

Breakpoint warning: Unexpected symbol reader error while processing helloworld.exe. - c:\RetireRecipe\Simulator\helloworld.cpp:5

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
}
```

Comment: What a strange issue.  Does it work after a full clean and rebuild?  Is the program database (.PDB file) readable?  If you delete that file and rebuild, does it help?  Have you tried copying your source file into another directory, creating a new empty console application project, adding this source file and compiling?  Or have you tried repairing/reinstalling Visual Studio?  Are you running anti-virus software on your computer?

Comment: Are you running in debug or release mode?

Comment: Restart VS. If not fixed,  Rebuild the application. And if all that doesn't work, start a new project and copy in the code.

Comment: Disable the installed anti-malware product and try again.

Comment: I wonder if it has generated a .pdb file and where it is kept. It seems like it cannot find a symbol file which I believe refers to the .pdb file.

Comment: Not sure the difference between debug mode and release mode. After compilation, I use F5 to run the debugger after setting a breakpoint. Program just blows through breakpoint leaving an empty circle where the breakpoint was. 'Breakpoint warning' message above appears when I hover over empty circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of reading various VS Code install videos, I ended up reinstalling twice. The overall solution for me was the reinstall and using the g++ compiler and gdb debugger. I can now set breakpoints, etc.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I suggest that you could try the following methods.

1. Select `Debbug->(APP) Properties`, and make suer they are consistent and `Debug`. Breakpoint operation can only be in Debug mode.

[image]

2. Clean the project, rebuild the project and check if this folder `Project Name\Debug` has .pdb by `Right click your project ->Open Floder in File Explorer`.
   [image]
3. Go to `Debug -> Options and Settings`. On the `Debugging/General page`, clear the `Require source files that exactly match the original version` option.
   [image]
   [image]
4. `Debug -> (app) Properties-> Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> change from Auto to Mixed`.
   [image]
5. `Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Debugging -> Generate Debug Info -> Generate Debug Information optimized for sharing and publishing`
   [image]
   If it still work, I suggest that you could reinstall VS.

Comment: I cannot find these settings. I am using Visual Studio Code. Perhaps these settings are from Visual Studio? I reinstalled Visual Studio Code and observe the same issues.

Comment: I added some pictures. By the way, is your compiler Visual Studio or VScode? They are two different compilers.

Comment: Thank you Barrnet Chou for your hard work. I really appreciate it. However, I am not able to find these menus. I believe there are large differences between VS Code and VS (which I believe your screenshots come from). That said, after I could not find any similar debugger configs as you posted, I reinstalled (twice) and chose the g++ compiler and gdb debugger. I now have a working debugger! I will post as solution.